# Authentication using Authlogic in rails without email column in user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I am using Authlogic for authentication in my ROR app. Previously i had used the normal authlogic email based login and had email and password fields. Now i want the users to login by multiple email ids and hence i removed the column 'email' from users table and added a new table mapping the users with their corresponding emails. I have written a new login method to identify the email from that table. The problem is that the UserSession has no credentials. Moreover i do not understand why the password field too has lost its credentials eventhough it is present in the user model. After i tweaked the session form and submitted, this is the error i get: "You did not provide any details for authentication." . Is there any way by which i make authlogic recognize the other table for the email and user table for the password?

Comment: Does using authlogic's 'validate_password_method' and writing your own password validation method help? http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/Authlogic/Session/Password/Config#verify_password_method-instance_method